# How to use Telegram API to authenticate users?

Tags: django, telegram

I'd like to use Telegram API to authenticate users to my Django website, like  what [tchannels.me](http://tchannels.me/) does.

I've read the [docs](https://core.telegram.org/api/auth) about authorization but could not figure out how to implement the API. So really appreciate if you can provide some useful hints, or better, a concrete example.

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score -2):

there is a project in github
[TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp)

you can figure out how it's work

Good Luck !!!